# How to increase UITableView height automatically after adding new cells in swift?

Tags: swift

I have implement a document picker in my controller. Now when I browse a document it is display in tableview cell. The problem is when i am browsing a document it is displaying in the tableview cell like this :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3UCc.png)

But I want that tableview height will automatically increase when a new cell will added to the tableview. And it should be looking like the below screenshot:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPVs4.jpg)

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a tableView for this? Why not use a stackview inside a scrollview?

Comment: Should I add a stackview and a label inside it or what ? Actually I am new to swift so any idea for how to use stackview for my requirements ?